# Change default font of Select2

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 plugin to add the search feature to my dropdowns. However, I want the font style of these drop downs to be set to the same font as my other fields: `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

My 'Select' HTML:

```
<label>Department</label>
<select class='js-example-basic-single' name="department" id="department" required>
  <option value="Dep 1">Dep 1 </option>
  <option value="Dep 2">Dep 2 </option> etc.....
</select>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
    placeholder: "Please Select an option",
    allowClear: true
  });
});
```

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this, but couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: could you not just check the html the plugin uses and override the css styles/classes with your own?

Answer (score 7):

**select2js** provide different *classes and id* selectors for different sections of the *Select HTML tag*.

For specific changing the Select OPTION **font-size**, we can use the following class selector to change the same acc to our requirement.

```
.select2-results__options{
        font-size:14px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

the only css class I needed to change (for single-selects) was:

```
.select2-selection__rendered {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wanted to change the background color of the Select2.  So what I did is found the select2 class name that controls that feature.  I added my desired color to the css of the same class name affecting that feature and made sure that updated css loaded after the select2 stylesheets.  I did some minor tweeks the same way to the jquery themes.

Comment: That is probably what I will have to do , but I was hoping I wouldn't have to lol.

Comment: Have you tried using !important to do the override before actually overriding the classes?  I do it sparingly but I do use it.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this feature this morning and it worked!  It uses containerCssClass.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .myFont {
            font-size:x-small;
        }
    </style>
    <select id="m"><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>
    <select id="n"><option>three</option><option>four</option></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#m").select2({ containerCssClass: "myFont" });
        $("#n").select2();
    </script>
```

The first box had tiny font, and the second one had regular font.
He also added the dropdownCssClass  option.

Comment: when I try this I get the following error: Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/containerCss

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it, I just needed the full version in order for it to work. <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>

Comment: I was just about to paste that info in to ensure we were n the same page :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class='js-example-basic-single' name="department" id="department" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" required>
    <option value="Dep 1">Dep 1 </option>
    <option value="Dep 2">Dep 2 </option> etc.....
    </select>
```