# How to change font in select2 kartik yii2

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I'm using select2 and i want to change the font of the values in my drop down

I've tried the options['style'=>'font-weight:bolder']

```php
    <?=   $form->field($model, 'faqid')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map( \app\models\Faq::find()->all(),
            'faqid', function ($model) {
                return $model['question'] .' - '. $model['answer'];
            }
        )
        ,
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select Question',
            'style' => 'font-weight:bolder'
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ])->label('Questions - Answers');
    ?>
```

at the end i would like to change the font of $model['question']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default font of Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299971/change-default-font-of-select2) or see [How to change font-family of Select2 widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597568/yii2-how-to-change-font-family-of-select2-widget/54599348#54599348)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the following classes that are added in the `select2-krajee.css` file. UPDATE: To clarify, you should always update those styles in your own files, as modifying the library files may lead to losing the changes after version update.

For the Placeholder and selected Option

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-selection{
   font-weight: bold, sans-serif !important;
}
```

For the Drop-down Options

```
.select2-container--krajee .select2-results__option{
    font-weight: bold, sans-serif !important;
}
```

As for the above code, what does happen to the `font-weight:bolder` property? The syntax is correct, so it should go somewhere. If you can lookup through the output HTML or edit your answer to include it.

If there something that is unclear, please ask below.

Comment: Better write this classes in your own css file because if select2 are update he loose this update

Comment: @Sfili_81 I've edited the answer with a clarification. I did not mean to update the library file, but use it as reference. Thank you for noting it.

Answer (score 0):

Override the following  css class, it is working for mine.

```
.select2-results__option--highlighted {
   background-color: #337ab7;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for my problem is to headers in select2.
in dropdown the question comes on top in bold and the answer below.
here's the code i used.

```php
        $faq = Faq::find()->asArray()->all();
        $data = [];
        foreach ($faq as $key => $value) {
            $data[$value['question']] = [ $value['faqid'] => $value['answer']];
        }
```

thanks everyone.